# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement. I am trying to insert the whole list as ones

Tags: python, mysql, database, list

**I am trying to save this list of string in my database table all at ones but it's giving me this error and I don't understand I am new to this so can you guys please help me**

```
data = ['Unknown', 'Saqlain', 'fahad', 'Unknown']

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

Date_raw = datetime.datetime.now()
Date = str(Date_raw.strftime("%d%A%b"))

mycursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE march ( {Date} VARCHAR(255))")
sqlfor = f"INSERT INTO march ({Date}) VALUES(%s)"


mycursor.execute(sqlfor, data)
mydb.commit()``
```

**It works like this but it stores all the names in a single column which i don't want I want all the names in different columns. also my data is dynamic so the list will be different every time**

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
Date_raw = datetime.datetime.now()
Date = str(Date_raw.strftime("%d%A%b"))

mycursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE march ( {Date} VARCHAR(255))")
sqlfor = f"INSERT INTO march ({Date}) VALUE(%s %s %s %s)"

mycursor.execute(sqlfor, data)
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError%3A+Not+all+parameters+were+used+in+the+SQL+statement.+

Comment: Aside - MySQL is an enterprise level, server RDBMS. Creating separate month tables with date-named columns is not good database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [`executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) which passes a sequence of params into execute call:

```
mycursor.executemany(sqlfor, [(d,) for d in data])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i INT(11);

SET @i=1;

data = ['Unknown', 'Saqlain', 'fahad', 'Unknown']

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

Date_raw = datetime.datetime.now()

Date = str(Date_raw.strftime("%d%A%b"))

mycursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE march ( {Date} VARCHAR(255))")

sqlfor = f"INSERT INTO march ({Date}) VALUES(%s)"

WHILE((SELECT ELT(@i,data)) IS NOT NULL)
DO
BEGIN

mycursor.execute(sqlfor, (SELECT ELT(@i,data));

SET @i:= @i+ 1;

mydb.commit();

END;
END WHILE;`



SELECT ELT(1,['100','101']) returns '100' .ELT () returns null when the index is out of bounds
```

Comment: i didn't get it what are you doing here??